# SpringBoot + Angular ng-view Issues

Tags: angularjs, spring

I'm new to Angular and I'm kind of learning js as I go, but I'm trying to run Angular on the front end with Spring Boot. By default Spring renders my index.html page normally, but I'm getting a 404 not found error when I try to go to the /login page. I've tried just about every url combination I can think of for the template url, but no luck. Because I'm new at Angular, I cannot determine if this is a Spring config issue or something simpler.

Angular controller app.js:

```
      var wishingWell = angular.module('wishingWell', [ 'ngRoute' ]);

            wishingWell.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

                $routeProvider.when('/', {
                    templateUrl : 'static/home.html',
                    controller : 'home'
                }).when('/login', {
                    templateUrl : 'static/login.html',
                    controller : 'navigation'
                }).otherwise('/');

                $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

            });

            wishingWell.controller('home', function($scope, $http) {
                $http.get('/resource/').success(function(data) {
                    $scope.greeting = data;
                })
            });

            wishingWell.controller('navigation', function() {});
```

index.html:

```
            <!doctype html>
            <html ng-app="wishingWell">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
                <meta name="viewport"
                      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"/>
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/normalize.css"/>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css"/>

                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
                <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script>
                <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"   integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="/javascript/Angular/app.js"></script>

                <title>Wishing Well</title>
            </head>

            <body ng-controller="home">
                    <nav class="nav">
                        <ul class="navback">
                            <li>
                                <a class="active" href="/">The Well</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/profile" >Profile</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/sign-up">Sign Up</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/login">Log In</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/logout">Sign Out</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>

                    <div ng-view></div>

            </body>
            </html>
```

folder structure:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: This 404 error has nothing to do with angular. Can you show us your url (localhost...) and your default controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Spring as clicking on login link is getting rendered on client side and not on server side (not an ajax call or page submit).

I can see few issues here:

-> In index.html link for angular-route is incorrect

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script>
```

it should be

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script>
```

you forgot https:

-> You need to use #/login in anchor tag, else your page will be redirected to .login that doesn't exists

```
 <a href="#/login">Log In</a>
```

->index.html and login.html are in same directory, so in app.js template url should be login.html and not static/login.html

You can see it working here
https://plnkr.co/edit/YpAm5FVG2ME7s3EeAigY?p=preview

Note: I have moved index.html outside static folder to make it work with plunker and updated app.js path in index.html accordingly.

If it still doesnt work, press f12 (if using chrome) an post console output.

Comment: I fixed everything you suggested but it will not inject the home.html into the ng-view for some reason. Here is what the console output is: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]   And it throws: throw $injectorMinErr('modulerr', "Failed to instantiate module {0} due to:\n{1}". Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think there is some going on with the file paths. I pasted the app.js script directly into the index.html, and the injector error disappeared, but now I'm getting a [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template, so it appears that none of my paths are working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause (@coder response found the surface level errors) of why these pages wouldn't load was that Spring security was blocking the file paths. I added the templates into the ant matchers and it works. This documentation is where I found this; something easily skipped over when going through it: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

```
                @Override
                protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                    http
                            .authorizeRequests()
                                .antMatchers("/index.html", "/sign-up.html","/login.html", "/").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                                .and()
                                .csrf().disable();

                }
```